# Python socket troubles

Tags: python-2.7

Maybe I am not understanding how sockets are supposed to work, so perhaps someone can help me. I though that the following would loop forever printing "Sent Hello. Received: Hello to you!", but in fact it loops twice and then hangs. No timeout, connection reset by peer, etc. Just hangs.

```
import socket

socket_list = []
for i in range(60000, 60002):
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.connect("",i)
    socket_list.append(soc)

while True:
   for soc in socket_list:
        soc.sendall("Hello.")
        msg = soc.recv(1024)
        print "Sent Hello. Received:",msg
```

The code on the other end of the connection is simply:

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind("localhost",6000x)
while True:
   soc.listen(1)
   conn, addr = soc.accept()
   msg = conn.recv(1024)
   if msg == "Hello":
       conn.sendall("Hello to you!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(60000, 60002):
    soc.connect("",i)
```

In the client program you open two sockets at startup and then use those sockets for the lifetime of your program.

```
while True:
   conn, addr = soc.accept()
```

In the server program you repeatedly `accept()` a new connection every iteration of the main loop. This successfully accepts the first connection on each port, performs one recv/send cycle, then starts over and tries to accept a new connection rather than continue using the existing socket.

One of the programs needs to change. Either your client program needs to call `socket()` and `connect()` inside its while loop, or your server program needs to move its `listen()` and `accept()` calls outside of its while loop.

Comment: Thank you, very  much. That indeed was the problem.